# shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier doesn't work with TabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an objective-C mobile app. I would like to check a condition, if it's true then the next screen should come up. If the condition is not true, the original (first) screen should stay. 
I'm using the shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier method in the view controller of my first screen.

Segue type: show. It's named to GoToNextScreen on the Storyboard.

I debugged the code, it goes into the "return NO" part of shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier, but the app still changes the screen to the next one, which is a TabBar. Can someone help me please? Any help would be very much appreciated.

My goal is this behaviour: 
if the condition is not true (and return No gets executed), the screen should stay as is. It should stay my first screen.

shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier from the view controller of the first screen:

```js
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {
            return NO;
}
```

Comment: you are returning true if self.fileExists == false at last.  - (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"GoToNextScreen"]) {
        if (self.fileExists == true) {
            return YES;
        }
        else {
            return NO;                // this line was executed but the screen still changed
        }
    }else
    {
      return NO;
    }   
}

Comment: I changed that last one to NO and it still switches the screen. I'm modifying it in my question as well

Comment: you can't add return No. If you do so , everytime it will return NO. Change it like I did in above comment

Comment: I tried your code, it still switches the screen

Comment: I think it's because I'm switching to a TabBar screen. I'm using the same code (my shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier code above) at another place in the app, and it works fine

Comment: I tried just return NO (above), it still switches the screen to the TabBar

Comment: can you post redirection code?

Comment: sorry, what is redirection code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185532/discussion-between-a-h-nuri-and-tio).

Comment: where you check this "shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier " from this method you are getting return type, and in somewhere you are calling and checking its return type. On the basis of that you move on.

Comment: How did you actually performed the `segue`? Have you invoked `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` method?